# getFiles and getFolders always return only one file/folder

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, constants

When trying to receive all files and folders from my Google Drive, the function `.getFiles()` returns only one file, and `.getFolders()` returns only one folder. **I do have multiple folders and files in my drive.**

My code:

```
function run() {
    try { 
        const folders = DriveApp.getFolders();
        const files = DriveApp.getFiles();

        while (folders.hasNext()) {
            const folder = folders.next();
            console.log(folder.getName())


            folder.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.PRIVATE, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT)
            if (folder.getSharingAccess() !== DriveApp.Access.PRIVATE)
              console.error("Permission was not changed, or changed incorrectly")
        }

        while (files.hasNext()) {
            const file = files.next();
            console.log(file.getName())
            file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.PRIVATE, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT)
            if (file.getSharingAccess() !== DriveApp.Access.PRIVATE)
              console.error("Permission was not changed, or changed incorrectly")
        }
    } catch (err) { 
      console.error(err)
    }
}
```

I expect `console.log(file.getName())` and `console.log(folder.getName())` to show the information about the different files, but it's always the same one:

```
Jan 8, 2019, 4:26:05 PM Debug TestFolder1NestedFolder1
Jan 8, 2019, 4:26:05 PM Debug TestFolder1NestedFolder1
Jan 8, 2019, 4:26:06 PM Debug TestFolder1NestedFolder1
Jan 8, 2019, 4:26:06 PM Debug TestFolder1NestedFolder1
Jan 8, 2019, 4:26:07 PM Debug TestFolder1NestedFolder1
Jan 8, 2019, 4:26:07 PM Debug TestFolder1NestedFolder1
Jan 8, 2019, 4:26:10 PM Debug Change Sharing to PRIVATE
Jan 8, 2019, 4:26:10 PM Debug Change Sharing to PRIVATE
Jan 8, 2019, 4:26:10 PM Debug Change Sharing to PRIVATE
Jan 8, 2019, 4:26:11 PM Debug Change Sharing to PRIVATE
Jan 8, 2019, 4:26:11 PM Debug Change Sharing to PRIVATE
Jan 8, 2019, 4:26:11 PM Debug Change Sharing to PRIVATE
Jan 8, 2019, 4:26:11 PM Debug Change Sharing to PRIVATE
```

Comment: Did you try DriveApp.getRootFolder().getFolders()?

Comment: tried that but it didn't help, but seems like i figured out the issue, its the const in the while loop... changing it to var fixed the issue. Such a silly mistake :) Thanks anyway

Comment: it's not really your fault that Apps Script doesn't have block-scoped `const`. Using `const` where appropriate is a good idea, but for Apps Script projects (for now at least) you should treat it as function-scoped assignment protection. http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/gassnips/constsandscopes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of the `const` key name for assignment in this situation is preventing you from getting the result that you want.

[JavaScript const - Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

> The value of a constant cannot change through reassignment, and it can't be redeclared

CURRENTLY:

```
const folder = folders.next();
```

CHANGE TO:

```
var folder = folders.next();
```

Answer (score -2):

Try changing `console.log` for `Logger.log` to view all the logs.

Comment: This doesn't do anything to resolve the OPs question. Stackdriver logs (`console.log`) are almost always more useful than the in-editor logs (`Logger.log`). Stackdriver logs persist for much longer, and actually are useful for debugging triggered functions for that reason. In-editor logs are cleared with every execution, and as such cannot provide a history of performance.